# How to cut off center part of images batch (imagemagick or mogrify)

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing, image-manipulation, gimp, mogrify

I've been trying to apply a batch modification for a while and couldn't find anything helpful, maybe because I don't have the right words to explain what I want to do. So here's an image I think is pretty clear...

[image: cut off center part of img]

Comment: Look at the "-chop" option in ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick.

Comment: How do we know how much to chop - I presume it isn't based on colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you start with this:

```
magick -size 600x400 gradient:cyan-magenta start.png
```

[image]

If you know a=100 and c=150, you will want to use this method:

```
convert start.png -write MPR:start -crop x100+0+0 \( MPR:start -gravity south -crop x150+0+0 \) -append result.png
```

[image]

The `MPR:start` is a temporary, RAM-based holding area, where I keep a copy of the full, original area while I chop the bottom off, and which I then recall before chopping the top off. Then, at the end, I append the two slices one above the other.

---

Or, you can use `-chop` as Glenn suggests, so if you know a=20 and b=200:

```
convert start.png -chop x200+0+20 z.png
```

[image]